# Get Client Hello from Wireshark

Tags: client-server, wireshark, packets

I need to get the Client Hello Cipher Suite for a website. The website is https://stripe.com/  When I start Wire-shark I start capturing and wait about 15 seconds then stop it and filter the data to

> ip.src == 54.187.119.242

*IP address changes every minute, need to ping stripe.com in cmd*

I get a Server Hello, but not a Client Hello. Am I not supposed to be getting the Client Hello? Here is the server Hello:

[image]
[image]

Do I need to wait more, or do something, or does it not show the Client Hello at all. Have not really used Wire Shark that much, so newbie question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want bi-directional traffic, you need to either specify `ip.addr == 54.187.119.242`, or filter on IP pairs, e.g.:

```
(ip.src == 54.187.119.242 && ip.dst == X.X.X.X) || (ip.src == X.X.X.X && ip.dst == 54.187.119.242)
```

Comment: Ok, the ip.addr worked, I get the Client Hello and Server Hello. Thank You!

Comment: You're welcome.  Keep in mind that `ip.addr == 54.187.119.242` is a sort of *macro* that essentially translates to, `ip.src == 54.187.119.242 || ip.dst == 54.187.119.242`.